# Create 3d array from 2 2d arrays

Tags: julia

Apologies in advance if this is a really silly question.

I have 2 arrays - `StartAmount` is a `165×11 Matrix{Float64}`: that contains 11 "types" of monetary values for 165 lives, and `IncreaseFactors` is a `100×11 Matrix{Float64}:` that contains 11 increase factors for each of 100 years.  I want to multiply these by each other such that my result is a 165x11x100 array, with each of the 11 "types" of amount increased for 100 years.  When I try `StartAmount .* IncreaseFactors` I get `ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 165 and 100")`.  I have already set up a 165x11x100 array of zeros, but I don't know how to populate it!

Any suggestions on how to manipulate my two arrays to create the 3D array I am after?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to turn `IncreaseFactors` into a 1x11x100 array, so that it can be dot-multiplied with `StartAmount`. You can do that by transposing `IncreaseFactors` and then using `reshape`, i.e. `reshape(transpose(IncreaseFactors), 1, 11, :)` or maybe `reshape(permutedims(IncreaseFactors), 1, 11, :)`

Answer (score 3):

[Tullio.jl](https://github.com/mcabbott/Tullio.jl) can abstract away many indexing notations nicely.

```
using Tullio

@tullio out[i,j,k] := StartAmount[i,j] * IncreaseFactors[k,j]
165×11×100 Array{Float64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 ...
```

It essentially does what the following 3-loop would do but without caring about indices:

```
out = [StartAmount[i,j] * IncreaseFactors[k,j] for i=1:165, j=1:11, k=1:100]
```